# Why does 3D source potential flow only satisfy Laplace's equation in spherical coordinates and not cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerodynamics

3D source potential flow is given by:
$\phi = \frac{-\lambda}{4\pi r}$.

Laplace's equation in cylindrical coordinates is:

$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\right) + f(\theta,z) = 0$

where $f(\theta,z) = 0$ since $\phi$ is independent of $\theta$ and $z$.

$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}(r \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}) = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r} \left(\frac{\lambda}{4\pi r}\right) = 
     \left(\frac{-\lambda}{4\pi r^3}\right) \neq 0$

Thus, the 3D potential flow is not a solution to Laplace's equation in cylindrical coordinates.

Now, Laplace's equation in spherical coordinates is:

$\frac{1}{r^2sin(\theta)}\left[\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r^2sin(\theta)\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\right) + f(\theta,\Phi)\right] = 0$

Where $f(\theta,\Phi) = 0$ since $\phi$ is independent of $\theta$ and $\Phi$.

$\frac{1}{r^2sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}
(r^2sin(\theta)\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}) = 
\frac{1}{r^2sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}
(r^2sin(\theta)\frac{\lambda}{4\pi r^2})=\frac{1}{r^2sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}(f(\theta))=0$

Therefore, source potential flow is a solution to Laplace's equation in spherical coordinates. As I understand it, a solution to Laplace's equation should be independent of coordinate system, so what is going on here?

All equations for this question have come from *John D. Anderson Jr., Fundamentals of Aerodynamics Fifth Edition.*

Comment: Despite the notation, the $r$ is not the same in the two different coordinate systems. One is distance from a point (the origin) the other is a distance from a line (the $z$ axis). So you haven't described the same potential for cylindrical coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate potential (from irrotational condition) for 2d would give you,

$\phi = \Lambda ~ln~r$.

Which gives,

$u_r = \frac{\lambda}{r}$  .

Please, check your definition of potential function again.